# JButtons grayed out / logic issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Im working on a voting program assignment in my first Java class. I'm almost finished except a weird issue with the JButtons for the candidate choices. They're disabled and greyed out after the first person voting votes (as they are when the window first launches). Then they're supposed to be enabled after the second person logs in. However whats happening is that all the buttons get disabled but seemingly random buttons will NOT appear greyed out (even though they are indeed disabled). Sometimes one or two of them also retain their red text color (which is enacted when a user clicks on them to select their voting choice). I do manipulate them in difference areas which Im guessing is leading to a logic error I can't seem to see.

[screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcAlS.png)
[screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIUAp.png)

```
//import section
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Assig4 {


    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {

        /* variables */

        String ballotsFileName = args[0]; // gets the file name from command line
        JFrame theWindow; //assign variable name for main window
        ArrayList <Ballot> ballotsAr = new ArrayList<>(); //creates array for jpanel ballot objects
        ArrayList <Integer> numVotes = new ArrayList<>();
        int numBallots=0;
        int counter = 0; //to count each file read in loop
        JButton login, submitVote;
        //voter variables
        ArrayList <Integer> voterIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList <String> voterNames = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList <Boolean> voterVoted = new ArrayList<>();

        /*create window*/

        theWindow = new JFrame ("Voting E Machine");
        theWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        theWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        /* read in ballot info and create ballot objects*/

        numBallots = readInBallotFile(ballotsFileName, numBallots, ballotsAr);

        /*read in data from voter file*/

        try {
            // method that accesses the file
            readInVoterFile(voterIdList, voterNames, voterVoted);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}

        /*add local components*/
        submitVote = new JButton("Submit Vote(s)");
        submitVote.setEnabled(false);
        login = new JButton("Login");

        /*actionListener class to handle login and vote submissions*/

        class MListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                //if submitVote button is clicked
                if (ae.getSource() == submitVote)
                {
                    //confirm submission
                    int selectedOption;
                    selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Confirm vote?","Choose",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                    if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please review selection");
                    else if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    {
                        //thank you message
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for your vote!");
                        //loop through each ballot and each candidate to update total votes
                        for (int bb =0; bb < ballotsAr.size(); bb++)
                        {
                            for (int s =0; s <ballotsAr.get(bb).getNumCandidates(); s++)
                            {
                                if (ballotsAr.get(bb).getVoteCount(s) >0)
                                    ballotsAr.get(bb).addTotalNumVotes(s);
                            }
                        }

                        try {
                            // method that accesses the file
                            writeVoterFile(voterIdList, voterNames, voterVoted);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {}
                        try {
                            // method that accesses the file
                            writeBallotResultsFiles(ballotsAr);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {}

                        //reset voter machine
                        login.setEnabled(true);
                        submitVote.setEnabled(false);
                        for (int gg = 0; gg <ballotsAr.size(); gg++)
                        {
                            ballotsAr.get(gg).disableCandidateButtons();
                        }

                    }

                } //end of if source is submit vote button

                //if login button is clicked
                if (ae.getSource() == login)
                {
                    String userEntryIdString;
                    int userEntryId;
                    boolean registered=false;

                    do {
                        userEntryIdString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your voter ID number: ");
                        userEntryId = Integer.parseInt(userEntryIdString);
                        //check id number against registered citizens
                        for (int v =0; v < voterIdList.size(); v++)
                        {
                            if (userEntryId == voterIdList.get(v) && !voterVoted.get(v))
                            {
                                registered = true;
                                voterVoted.set(v,true);
                                login.setEnabled(false);
                                //print welcome message with name
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, voterNames.get(v) + ", please make your choices");
                            }
                            else if (userEntryId == voterIdList.get(v) && voterVoted.get(v))
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU HAVE ALREADY VOTED. If think this is an error precede.");
                        }   // end of loop to check id against id list

                        if (registered)
                        {
                            //enable buttons
                            for (int j = 0; j<ballotsAr.size(); j++)
                            {
                                ballotsAr.get(j).enableCandidateButtons();
                            }
                            submitVote.setEnabled(true);
                        }

                        else if (!registered)
                            System.out.println("Please try again. ");
                    } while (!registered);
                } //end of if login button is clicked
            } //end of action performed method

        }// end of actionlistener

        /*create action listener object */
        ActionListener listener2 = new MListener();

        /*add Ballot panels*/
        addPanels(theWindow, ballotsAr);

        /*assign components to actionlistener*/
        submitVote.addActionListener(listener2);
        login.addActionListener(listener2);

        /* Add local buttons to window */
        theWindow.add(login);
        theWindow.add(submitVote);

        /*pack and set window to visible*/

        theWindow.pack();
        theWindow.setVisible(true);

    }   //end of main

    public static int readInBallotFile(String ballotsFile, int numBallots, ArrayList<Ballot> ballotsAr) throws IOException
    {
        int counter = 0;
        //objects - open and setup scanner for file
        File myfile = new File (ballotsFile);
        Scanner textScan = new Scanner(myfile); // reads in date from text file
        numBallots = Integer.parseInt(textScan.nextLine()); //read in first line (number of ballots) and parse to int
        while (textScan.hasNextLine()) //one ballot's data for each loop
        {

            //read in each ballot's info
            //take the first line as a string
            String [] tempStr = textScan.nextLine().split(":");
            //parse line into proper data values
            int tempId = Integer.parseInt(tempStr[0]); //take first value for id
            String tempCategory = tempStr[1]; // take second value as category type
            String [] tempCandidates = tempStr[2].split(","); // takes the arbitrary number of candidates and splits into separate string variables

            //create ballot object
            ballotsAr.add(new Ballot(tempId,tempCategory,tempCandidates, ballotsFile));
            counter++; //adds counter to while loop
        }   // end of loop to read in ballot text file contents
        textScan.close(); //closes ballots.txt file
        return numBallots;
    }   //end of read in ballot file method

    public static void addPanels(JFrame theWindow, ArrayList <Ballot> ballotsAr)
    {
        for (int i =0; i<ballotsAr.size();i++)
        {
            theWindow.add(ballotsAr.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void readInVoterFile(ArrayList <Integer> _voterIdList, ArrayList <String> _voterNames, ArrayList <Boolean> _voterVoted) throws IOException
    {
        int counter = 0;
        //objects - open and setup scanner for file
        File myfile = new File ("voters.txt");
        Scanner textScan = new Scanner(myfile); // reads in date from text file
        while (textScan.hasNextLine()) //one voter's data for each loop
        {
            //take the first line as a string
            String [] tempStr = textScan.nextLine().split(":");
            //parse line into proper data values
            _voterIdList.add(Integer.parseInt(tempStr[0]));  //take first value for voter id
            _voterNames.add(tempStr[1]); // take second value as voter name
            _voterVoted.add(Boolean.parseBoolean(tempStr[2]));
            counter++; //adds counter to while loop
        }   // end of loop to read in voter text file contents
        textScan.close(); //closes ballots.txt file
    } // end of voter read in method

    //update voter file local variables including false to true for voted
    //write data to temp file
    //delete original file
    //change temp file name to previous file name

    //create ballot files
    //reset voterprogram

    public static void writeVoterFile(ArrayList <Integer> voterIdList, ArrayList <String> voterNames, ArrayList <Boolean> voterVoted) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("tempVotersFile.txt");
        for (int q = 0; q < voterIdList.size(); q++)
        {
            outputFile.print(voterIdList.get(q)+":");
            outputFile.print(voterNames.get(q)+":");
            String tempStrboolean = String.valueOf(voterVoted.get(q));
            if (q == voterIdList.size()-1) //avoid blank line at end of text file
                outputFile.print(tempStrboolean);
            else
                outputFile.println(tempStrboolean);
        }
        outputFile.close();

        //change temp file name to voters.txt
        File tempFile = new File ("tempVotersFile.txt");
        File originalFile = new File ("voters.txt");
        tempFile.renameTo(originalFile);
    }   //end of write voter method

    public static void writeBallotResultsFiles(ArrayList <Ballot> _ballotsAR) throws IOException
    {
        for (int h = 0; h <_ballotsAR.size(); h++)
        {
            String tempStr = String.valueOf(_ballotsAR.get(h).getId());
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(tempStr);
            for (int r = 0; r <_ballotsAR.get(h).getNumCandidates(); r++)
            {
                outputFile.print(_ballotsAR.get(h).getCandidateString(r)+":");
                outputFile.println(_ballotsAR.get(h).getTotalNumVotes(r));
            } //end of loop for number of candidates for each ballot
            outputFile.close();
        } // end of loop for each ballot

    }   // end of write ballot results method

} // end of class



//import section
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Ballot extends JPanel {

    //instance variables
    private int id;
    private JLabel categoryLabel;
    private String categoryS, ballotsFileName;
    private ArrayList <JButton> candidatesButton = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    private ArrayList<String> candidatesS = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int [] numVotes;
    private int [] totalNumVotes;  // total votes for all voters
    private boolean[] clicked;

    //constructor
    public Ballot(int _id,String _category,String [] _candidatesS, String _ballotsFileName)
    {
        //set variables
        id = _id;
        categoryS = _category;
        ballotsFileName = _ballotsFileName;
        for (int t= 0; t<_candidatesS.length; t++)
        {
            candidatesS.add(_candidatesS[t]);
        } //end of loop to copy array to arrayList
        categoryLabel = new JLabel(categoryS);
        numVotes = new int [candidatesS.size()];
        totalNumVotes = new int [candidatesS.size()];


        //align label
        categoryLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        //make bold
        Font f = categoryLabel.getFont();
        categoryLabel.setFont(f.deriveFont(f.getStyle() ^ Font.BOLD));

        // set layout for ballot panel
        setLayout(new GridLayout(candidatesS.size()+1,1));

        //add the category label to the panel
        add(categoryLabel);

        //create action listener object
        ActionListener listener = new BListener();

        //loop to create arbitrary number of candidate buttons
        clicked = new boolean[candidatesS.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < candidatesS.size(); i++)
        {
            candidatesButton.add(new JButton(candidatesS.get(i)));
            clicked[i] = false;
            candidatesButton.get(i).addActionListener(listener);
            add(candidatesButton.get(i));
            candidatesButton.get(i).setEnabled(false);
        } // end of loop
    }   //end of ballot constructor

    //method to return click status
    public boolean getStatusClicked(int i)
    {
        return clicked[i];
    }

    //accessor methods
    public String getCategoryS() {return categoryS;}
    public String getCandidateString(int i) {return candidatesS.get(i);} //not right
    public int getNumCandidates() {return candidatesButton.size();}
    public int getId() {return id;}
    public int getVoteCount(int i) {return numVotes[i];}
    public int getTotalNumVotes (int i) {return totalNumVotes[i];}

    //mutator methods
    public void enableCandidateButtons()
    {
        for (int g = 0; g<candidatesS.size(); g++)
        {
            candidatesButton.get(g).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    public void disableCandidateButtons() //disable and reset buttons after one person votes
    {
        for (int g = 0; g<candidatesS.size(); g++)
        {
            candidatesButton.get(g).setEnabled(false);
            clicked[g] = false;
            candidatesButton.get(g).setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public void addTotalNumVotes(int i) {totalNumVotes[i]++;}
    //listener to toggle the status of buttons when clicked
    private class BListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int i = 0; //counter variable for arraylist calls
            for (JButton b: candidatesButton) //change to REGULAR FOR LOOP??
            {
                if (e.getSource() == candidatesButton.get(i))
                {
                    clicked[i] = !clicked[i];
                    if (clicked[i])
                    {
                        candidatesButton.get(i).setForeground(Color.RED);
                        numVotes[i]++;
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,numVotes[i]); debugging option to check vote count

                    }

                    else if (!clicked[i])
                    {
                        candidatesButton.get(i).setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                        numVotes[i]--;
                    }
                } // end of if get source is
                else
                {
                    candidatesButton.get(i).setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    clicked[i] =false;
                    numVotes[i] = 0;
                }

                i++; //increment int counter
            } // end of cycle through all buttons
        } // end of actionperformed
    } //end of listener



} // end of ballot class
```

Comment: Consider re-writing, and in doing so, getting **most** of that code out of the main method, out of the static realm and into the instance realm where it fully belongs.

Comment: Yeah, looking at it now I can see that for sure but its due tomorrow and its taken me quite a while to get this far haha.

Comment: Well, I sincerely wish you good luck, and hope that you solve your issue before your deadline.